# Azure Data Factory : If Pipeline A starts, then Pipeline B ( if it is running ) stops "until" Pipeline A ends

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am very new to Azure Data Factory
I want to do the following:

IF  Pipeline A starts THEN Pipeline B should stop and not start until Pipeline A is finished.

How do we achieve this?

I was trying a few links but since I am new , nothing really worked. I want to get an idea on how I can start this.

How do I call the REST API here? this is my JSON Structure

Edit:

```
{
    "name": "p_Stop_go_Test_2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "yyyyy",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "get pStopgoTest runs based on filters",
                "description": "get p_Stop_go_Test runs based on filters.",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Check if response is empty or not",
                "description": "in the rest api response if the values array is empty then pStopgoTest is not in running state",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "get pStopgoTest runs based on filters",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "pipeline pStopgoTest2 acitivites",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Cancle Pipeline pStopgoTest",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "pipeline pStopgoTest2 activities",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Cancle Pipeline pStopgoTest",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Re-run pipeline pStopgoTest",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "pipeline pStopgoTest2 activities",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "xxx"
    },
    "type": "xxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add few activities before and after the current activities present in pipeline B.
- First check whether there is a pipeline named `pipelineA` which is in running state (In progress) using [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP)
- In the response, if the values array is empty, then pipeline A is not in running state and therefore implement the rest of the logic. Else, first cancel that pipeline run using [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/cancel?tabs=HTTP).
- Now that the pipeline A condition is dealt with, you can implement the activities of your pipelineB. If you want to continue running the pipeline A at the end, you can use another rest API for it.
- The following is how the flow looks like for the above implementation:

[image]